# 3.0 -- Paginator & Custom Routing issues

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use the built in paginator helper in 3.0, however; it's throwing a 'Missing Route' exception...

**Route code:**

```
Router::prefix('manage', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/:organizationNeedle',['controller'=>'Organizations','action' => 'dashboard']);
    $routes->connect('/:organizationNeedle/:controller',['action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/:organizationNeedle/:controller/:action/*');
});
```

**View Template code:**

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
```

**Result:**

None of the currently connected routes match the given URL or parameters. Add a matching route to `config\routes.php`

The passed context was:

```
[
    '_base' => '',
    '_port' => '80',
    '_scheme' => 'http',
    '_host' => 'vlife.v4',
    'params' => [
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'Containers',
        'action' => 'index',
        '_ext' => null,
        'pass' => [],
        'organizationNeedle' => 'test',
        'prefix' => 'manage',
        'paging' => [
            'Containers' => [
                [maximum depth reached]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have tried several combinations of different routes, but can't find one that does not throw this error. If I add `$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');` to my route info it no longer throws the error, however; the links generated point to `/manage/*controller*?page=2` instead of the proper `/manage/*organization*/*controller*?page=2`

Comment: Did you try `$routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');`?

Comment: That causes the issue stated at the end. So the links would improperly link to /o/menu_items?page=2 instead of /o/joes/menu_items?page=2 -- I've written a custom helper that overrides the offending paginator helper methods, but I'd love to know if there is an actual proper solution to this.

Comment: Open a ticket in github, this looks like a bug